# Hot to sent Data from list to Combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm looking to write the data from `listOfColumns` to a combobox, this is the code I have :

```
connectionString = "Server=localhost;User Id=root; Password=1234; Database=db2; Pooling=false;CharSet=utf8;";
connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

connection.Open();
string sql = "SELECT * FROM data where id = '"+textBox1.Text.Trim()+"'";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable schema = rdr.GetSchemaTable();
Dictionary<int, String> columnNames = new Dictionary<int, string>();
int index = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
{
   columnNames.Add(index, row[schema.Columns["ColumnName"]].ToString());
   index++;
}

List<String> listOfColumns = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
{
   var val = rdr[i];
   if ("1" == val)
   {
      /* if the value of the column is 1,
         add the column name from the dictionary */
      listOfColumns.Add(columnNames[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: yourcombobox.DataSource=listOfColumns; Something like this.I assume you already have a combobox and you are trying to set value to combobox.?

Comment: `Combobox` ? then why you have `columnNames[i]`?

Comment: ok  i got all code .Can you understand?

Answer (score 4):

Initialize a generic list string object.

```
List<string> listOfColumns = new List<string>();
```

Populate your list string with values.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= rdr.Count; i++)
{
    string value = rdr[i];
    if(value == "1")
    {
         listOfColumns.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Now you have your list string to bind to **ComboBox**.

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = listOfColumns;
comboBox1.DataSource = bs;
```

**UPDATE:** The following **DataBind() method** is for **WebForms**. You don't need to call it in **WinForms**. The above code should work:

```
comboBox1.DataBind();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thk i get some error from "comboBox1.DataBind();" Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
"

Comment: Try without the `DataBind` line - I think that's WPF, not Windows Forms.

Comment: @user3802389 Yeah @ThorstenDittmar is right. `DataBind()` is for WebForms. So if you are developing Winforms, remove that line. It should work.

Comment: @user3802389 If my solution solved your problem, please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the data binding way illustrated by Jowie, you can also do this manually:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= rdr.Count; i++)
{
    string value = rdr[i];
    if(value == "1")
    {
         listOfColumns.Add(value);
    }
}

foreach (string listItem in listOfColumns)
    comboBox1.Items.Add(listItem);
```

Actually, if you don't need `listOfColumns` for anything else, you can just do:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= rdr.Count; i++)
{
    string value = rdr[i];
    if(value == "1")
    {
         comboBox1.Items.Add(value);
    }
}
```